# Java split by \\S

Tags: java, regex

I am doing some study about regex. I tried with

```
public static void main(String[] agrs) {

    String s = "I am preparing ocp";
    String[] tokens = s.split("\\S");
    System.out.println(tokens.length);
    for (String x : tokens) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

and the result shown is 13 whitespaces.

However, when I add a whitespace behind the string as below,

```
public static void main(String[] agrs) {

    String s = "I am preparing ocp ";
    String[] tokens = s.split("\\S");
    System.out.println(tokens.length);
    for (String x : tokens) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

the result will be 16.

I dont quite understand how this regex works in this situation..anyone can enlighten me?

Comment: You shouldn't change your question once it was answered correctly. After changing your question from `s.split("\\S")` to `s.split("a")` you are asking a complete different question. For this case you should mark this one as resolved and ask a new one.

Comment: @Beginner you can create a new question for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to split on `\\s` (lowercase s) instead of uppercase s.

The way you have it now you are saying ***non***-whitespace characters are delimiters, leaving nothing but whitespace as your "data".

Also, it should probably be `\\s+` to allow multiple contiguous spaces as delimiters.

Comment: This REALLY doesn't answer the question.  Why are there three additional whitespaces when just one whitespace is added to the string?