# Java Regex Split \\S --> Strange result for String split methode \\S

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I am puzzled about the split methode with regex in Java. It is a rather theoretical question that poped up and i can't figure it out.

I found this answer: [Java split by \\S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111268/java-split-by-s)
but the advice to use \\s instead of \\S does not explain what is happening here.

Why: does quote.split("\\S") has 2 results in case A and 8 in case B ?

case A)

```
String quote = " x xxxxxx";
String[] words = quote.split("\\S"); 
System.out.print("\\S >>\t");
for (String word : words) {
  System.out.print(":" + word);
}
System.out.println(words.length);
```

Result:

\\S >> : : 2

case B)

```
String quote = " x xxxxxx ";
String[] words = quote.split("\\S"); 
System.out.print("\\S >>\t");
for (String word : words) {
  System.out.print(":" + word);
}
System.out.println(words.length);
```

Result:

\\S >> : : :::::: 8

It would be wonderfull to understand what happens here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java split by \\S](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111268/java-split-by-s)

Comment: `\\S` splits the string based on a non-whitespace character.

Comment: Hm, this is truly puzzling behavior. Expression `"a:b:::::".split(":")` evaluates to `[a,b]`, while `"a:b:::::c".split(":")` evaluates to `[a,b,,,,,c]`. Looks like this method ignores delimiters at the end of the string.

Comment: @uraf: it says so in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)): "Trailing empty strings are **therefore** not included in the resulting array." (my emph.)

Comment: Hi Jongware i read the documentation (ofcourse) : "This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array". That explains the 2 from case A but why is case B 8 -> should this logic not result in 2 as well instead of 8 (leaving out the trailing empty strings ?) To extend the question -> why results String quote = "xxxxxxxx"; in 0 . Are they all trailing empty strings ? Why is this not 1 (leaving out all the other trailing empty strings ?

Comment: Oh. If it says so then it's not puzzling at all. @irJvV, `\S` matches any **single** non-whitespace, including `x`. If you want to collapse multiple delimiters into one use `\S+`.

Comment: @uraf is right. The elements *in between* are not removed -- "trailing" means "only those at the end".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jongware noticed, the documentation for [String.split(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) says:

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with
>   the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty
>   strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

So it works somewhat like this:

```
"a:b:::::".split(":")  === removeTrailing([a,b,,,,,])  === [a,b]
"a:b:::::c".split(":") === removeTrailing([a,b,,,,,c]) === [a,b,,,,,c]
```

And in your example:

```
" x xxxxxx".split("\\S")  === removeTrailing([ , ,,,,,,])  === [ , ]
" x xxxxxx ".split("\\S") === removeTrailing([ , ,,,,,, ]) === [ , ,,,,,, ]
```

To collapse multiple delimiters into one, use `\S+` pattern.

```
" x xxxxxx".split("\\S+")  === removeTrailing([ , ,])  === [ , ]
" x xxxxxx ".split("\\S+") === removeTrailing([ , , ]) === [ , , ]
```

As suggested in the comments, to maintain the trailing empty strings we can use overloaded version of split method ([String.split(String, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)) with a negative number passed as limit.

```
"a:b:::::".split(":", -1)  === [a,b,,,,,]
```

Comment: It may be worth mentioning this is not particular to `\S` "as opposed to `\s`", they behave the same. The funny thing is that is also the correct answer for the linked question!

Comment: Great thanks for the clear and understandable answer !

Comment: I tested @uraf's answer om my extended question: "xxxxxxxx".split("\\S") === removeTrailings([,,,,,,,]) === [] All empty are removed from back to front leaving 0 results ;-)

Comment: @Jongware, right. It doesn't really have anything to do with `\S` in particular.

Comment: Jongware @uraf i tested it for \\W and \\w as well. Actualy you implicitly use "a:b:::::".split(":",0) with a result of 2 elements If you want all the splits in your result you have to use "a:b:::::".split(":",-1) that results in 7 elements. Just to complete the answers on the question Thanks Again !

Comment: I found this answer searching for public String[] split(String regex, int limit) --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21575452/java-strings-split-method-ignores-empty-substrings The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded. For anyone interested !